# Readingvalues from td ids from table

Tags: jquery

I have a table as follows and upon clicking the edit button I want to read it`s rows values from the td ids

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="Name">111</td>
      <td id="surname">aaaa</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="edit" value="edit"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Name">123</td>
      <td id="surname"></td>vvv
      <td><input type="button" id="edit" value="edit"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="Name">122</td>
      <td id="surname">vvvvv</td>
      <td><input type="button" id="edit" value="edit"/></td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't have several elements with the same ID.. You should use `class` instead, which would allow you to use `$$('.className')` to get all elements with a specific class name

Comment: Unfortunately your HTML-Markup is full of errors. Id-Attributes are always unique within the whole document, but you use the id "surname" and "edit" several times. Use classes instead, their usage is unlimited. What do you want to achieve exactly? Do want to read the ids on clicking a button or the value of the td-field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

### js

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input[type=button]').click ( function () {
        var fName = $(this).parents("tr").find("td.Name").html();
        var surName = $(this).parents("tr").find("td.surName").html();
        alert('\nName:'+fName +' surName:'+surName +'\n');
});
```

#### revised HTML:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=5>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">111</td>
        <td class="surName">aaaa</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="edit" value="edit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">123</td>
        <td class="surName">vvv</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="edit" value="edit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">122</td>
        <td class="surName">vvvvv</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="edit" value="edit"></td>
    </tr>
```

### [DeMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xSVp3/1/)

Comment: The example is great, but the revised HTML should address the non unique ID issue - i.e. an answer shouldn't include something that is wrong. (id="Name" used multiple times)

Comment: As parents() will return all ancestors the use of closest() is preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your markup. Firstly Ids should always be unique. If you want to apply a common name across multiple elements then a class would be a better idea.
Also you seem to be missing some table rows. Assuming this is corrected you should be able to access the value you require in a multiple of ways:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">111</td>
        <td class="surname">aaaa</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">123</td>
        <td class="surname">vvv</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Name">122</td>
        <td class="surname">vvvvv</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="edit" value="edit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming this is the markup then:

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    var idVal = $(this).parent().siblings('.Name').html();
    alert(idVal);
});
```

or

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    var idVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html();
    alert(idVal);
});
```

using scopes

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    var idVal = $('.Name', $(this).closest('tr')).html();
    alert(idVal);
});
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

First there are quite a few little error errors (the 7th td is missing an opening tag). Also an id should only be used once, you can't/shouldn't have id='name' x3, or id='surname' x3.

Once they are fixed up, you can use the following jquery to grab an id:

```
$("#surname").html(); // where surname is the id
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for the Name:

```
$('input:button')
 .click(function(){alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td[id="Name"]').text());});
```

(Assuming that you forgot some rows inside your code)

But as an ID has to be unique, you should better remove the ID's and try using the index of the td's:

```
$('input:button')
 .click(function(){alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());});
```

(This will for example find the 2nd `<td>`, whose ID actually is "surname")